# Looping MySQL Results With Additional Queries

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me conceptualize a solution to a PHP page I'm writing.

Effectively, I have one master table in a MySQL database called "Servers."  In it are four fields; **department**, **serverA**, **serverB**, **serverC**.  For context, the department entry is the name of a department, and serverA, serverB, and serverC correspond to hostnames of the three servers for each department.

What I am trying to do is grab the name(s) of the department, serverA, serverB, and serverC and use that data to populate multiple SQL queries.  I have my data separated into multiple tables for cleanliness and relationship.  Here's what I've got;

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("server", "root", "root") or die('Error connecting to MySQLserver.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Database") or die("Failed to connect to database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Servers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $deptartment = $row['department']
    $serverA = $row['serverA'];
    $serverB = $row['serverB'];
    $serverC = $row['serverC'];
}
} else {
echo "Unable to connect to server.  Please check your settings.";
}
?>
```

What I'd then like to do is to do a sort of *foreach*, wherein *foreach* record of serverA, the following happens;

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("server", "root", "root") or die('Error connecting to MySQLserver.');
mysqli_select_db($conn, "Database") or die("Failed to connect to database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE `serverName` = '$serverA' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $serverName = $row['serverName'];
    $serverType = $row['serverType'];
    $serverAge = $row['serverAge'];
}
} else {
echo "Unable to connection to server.  Please check your settings.";
}
?>
```

I could then use the same theory to loop through the results of **serverB** and have each record for serverB fulfill another query to get other data.

I seem to be struggling with the right syntax for how to loop through each of the results and populate other queries with it.

Any possible guidance?

Thank you!

```
Sample Data:
department: Math
serverA: math-server-windows.school.edu
serverB: math-server-mac.school.edu
serverC: math-server-linux.school.edu

department: Psychology
serverA: psychology-server-windows.school.edu
serverB: psychology-server-mac.school.edu
serverC: psychology-server-linux.school.edu

department:  Arts
serverA: artsserver.school.edu
serverB: artsold.school.edu
serverC: artsbackup.school.edu
```

Comment: you would be well served to include your actual table definitions, and some sample data.

Comment: What determines whether a given server is a, b, or c

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity!  I've updated my post with an example of what one would find in the "Servers" table.  There is an example of three rows above.  Thank you!!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Instead of doing loops in loops, you could probably do this with a `JOIN` query - `SELECT * FROM Servers JOIN Data ON Data.serverName = Servers.serverA ORDER BY \`timestamp\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JOINs to make this much simpler.

Table `Data` has a field `servername` that corresponds to either `serverA`, `serverB` or `serverC` in the servers table. So you can run a query like so:

```
SELECT Data.*,
  A.serverA AS serverA, 
  B.serverB AS serverB, 
  C.serverC AS serverC 
FROM Data
JOIN servers as A on Data.servername = A.serverA
JOIN servers as B on Data.servername = B.serverB
JOIN servers as C on Data.servername = C.serverC
ORDER BY <whatever>
```

So now each row will have the server information for each department, so loop through the results like so:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
  echo "\nDept: ".$row['department'];
  echo "\nA: ".$row['serverA'];
  echo "\nB: ".$row['serverB'];
  echo "\nC: ".$row['serverB'];
}
```

Comment: This worked well!  Thank you for the suggestion.  I have some syntax issues to figure out with getting my data to encode as JSON data, but I am properly pulling from the various tables and the initial question has been answered.  Thank you!